# How do I get a bootstrap button in the center of the page?

Tags: css

I want my button aligned in the middle of the page but when using my code it doesn't work.

my code:

```
button {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
max-width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean horizontally centered? Or you want it vertically centered in the page, too?

Answer (score 1):

You should utilize the bootstrap classes over custom CSS when you can.

Use `.text-center` on the parent.

```css
button 
{
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="text-center">
  <button>button</button>
</div>
```

Or if you don't want to do that, just add `.center-block` (or `display: block`) to the button.

```css
button 
{
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <button class="center-block">button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing in `margin: 0 auto`;

Comment: yes, using `margin` only itself should do it, instead of `margin-left` and `margin-right` also if you want to make it responsive you can `margin:10% auto`

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div>
    <button>
        Hello
    </button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
button {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 max-width: 100px;
}

div {
 text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox to center it.

```
div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```